# Any Commercial/Open Source swing alternative?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am absolutely new to java and the GUI that swing gives me looks pretty ugly.

I was wondering if there is any swing alternative that gives program good looks.Like for example there are radforms for .net.

Comment: "looks pretty ugly" You know it's skinnable and cutomizable, right? You can set it to the system's native look (so it looks like your system's windows) and/or try any of the included or downloadable skins.

Comment: Well as i just said i am new to java so i didn't knew about it. On the other question well i don't find windows 7 native look and feel to be good. That's why i use radforms in the fist place.

Comment: You can try Apache pivot at http://pivot.apache.org/  Any GUI will have a learning curve, especially if you're looking to skin the components.

Comment: If you're coding just for Win, then use a Win-specific language such as C#. There's no need to futz with Java for your goals. Voting to close question as inappropriate for this site (invites debate...).

Answer (score 2):

SWT + JFace are an awesome (and platform independent) alternative.

Check this out:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace

Later edit: Oh, and, by the way, Swing has Look and Feel capabilities that might be closer to what you're looking for (now that I've researched what radforms are): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/

Answer (score 2):

+1 for @deepdownunder2222's answer.

You can also try:

- [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html)
- [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) (mainly for web applications)

Answer (score 2):

Swing is skinnable, so if you don't like the default skin, you can choose one of the included ones, use the system's default (so that the dialogs look like OS dialogs), or try some of the [free skins from the internet](http://www.javootoo.com/).

---

If you're coming from C++, you might know Qt which is pretty much a standard there.

Qt Java bindings are called [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/). There are some [examples](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-examples.html) on the site, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/)
and you have more benefits like:

- Write less code to have component
- Good component Descriptor like Visual Studio, using XML to define a Component like label, Textbox, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Swing doesn't look as beautiful as native GUI, but it also has a killer excuse for it: it looks OK on every Java-supporting platform. Anyway, that's the very reason people decide to use Java for their application. If you are developing for just one platform then do consider a native framework instead. On Java you can also try SWT, the framework used to build Eclipse.

Comment: I am planning to build just for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is skinnable - you can make it look and feel however you like.

See e.g.: http://geeknizer.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10/

The big advantage of Swing is that it works pretty consistently on all platforms, and is available as part of the standard Java runtime so you don't need to worry about extra dependencies.

There are alternatives, but they generally have some limitations (e.g. being tied to specific platforms or native libraries). The other leading options are probably:

- JavaFX
- SWT
- LWJGL (for OpenGL 3D interactive / game applications)
- Android